# Moving picture ontouch

Tags: android, slide

I'm trying to move A picture in android, but I really don't find A way to do it. I used already several methods but none of them really worked, this is my code at the moment

```
public class Tangram extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
ImageView img;
int x=0,y=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.tangram);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tangrampic1);
    img.setOnTouchListener(this);
    img.scrollBy(x, y);
}

 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    { 
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {      
                  x++;
                     break; 
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {             
                  x--;  
                 break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

}

Does anybody know how to move an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it the following way:
 - implement your own view 
 - in the ondraw method of this view paint your image ( starting with offset 0/0 )
 - onTouch move the offset and invalidate the view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out this -

```
surf.setOnTouchListener( new SurfaceView.OnTouchListener(){
              public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if( moving ){
                        final int x_new = (int)event.getX();
                        final int y_new = (int)event.getY();
                        mDrawTiles.draw( new DrawLogic(){
                            @Override
                            public void draw(Rect _surface) {
                                mTiles.setBounds(
                                    x_new - mDrawWidth/2,
                                    y_new - mDrawHeight/2,
                                    x_new + mDrawWidth/2,
                                    y_new + mDrawHeight/2);
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

And, refer [this](http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/touch-and-drag-in-android/) also.